# System Proxy Settings Being Ignored by Apps

Tags: windows, qt, proxy, virtual-machine

I want an app I am testing to use Win (10) OS system proxy settings. I'm watching packets on the proxy and see HTTPS browsing traffic on Chrome (I've installed a self signed cert on Win).

I can also see a few other OS requests coming through the proxy server. For some reason though, some apps don't pay attention to the system proxy settings.

Is there any way to force all connections through the proxy server? The app I'm testing uses Qt - QWebView. I found a reference [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41495-Set-a-proxy-for-QWebView) that you need to change the source to use a proxy. This won't work for me as I only have access to the production binary for this test.

How can I force an OS proxy connection, or otherwise route that traffic through my proxy?

Note my OS is in a virtual machine.

Edit: I'm wondering if editing the hosts file could route the traffic for a particular URL to my Proxy? I'm trying [Acrylic](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome) but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: If an application doesn't respect the proxy settings, you can't force it to do so.  (It might be possible to route all traffic for the VM through a transparent proxy, VPN, or similar but that's a Super User question.)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Unfortunately the general thought behind proxying VMs is that it's to be done in the guest OS.

Comment: Not necessarily - a transparent proxy would typically live on the network.  And I see no fundamental reason why a transparent proxy couldn't be implemented on the host, as a plugin to the virtualization software.  I don't know if there are any existing products to do that.  But you could run a VPN-type solution in the guest OS, at least in principle.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too. It's a good idea. But my Googling just led me to people saying VM deals with hardware, and proxy settings, being software were a guest OS configuration. I do see what you're saying though.

Comment: Proxy *settings* are an *application* configuration.  The OS may provide recommendations, but the application has to choose to implement them.  But a transparent proxy doesn't require any settings.